# Changing Elastic Beanstalk to Load Balanced breaks it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment running as a single instance. When changing to a load balanced configuration it completely breaks.

All the instances fail the automatically created health check despite the port specified being correct.

The ELB and the instances seem to be on the same VPC and subnet (they are both automatically created by EB).

I assigned a public EIP to one of the instances to try and connect to it to check the logs and suddenly that instance started to pass the health check and everything worked. If I remove the public EIP then the instance starts to fail the health check again.

What might be causing this and how can I debug it more effectively?